# Spring MVC + Hibernate not doing anything to the DB, no exceptions thrown

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I'm at a loss for a solution. I've been playing with Spring MVC and Hibernate, and I had established a connection with my database, pulling data, no problem.

I added an @Entity, and maybe done some other changes, and now Hibernate won't do anything. By anything, I mean there is no SQL executed (as shown in the tomcat logs, using the show-sql option of hibernate). There is also no exceptions thrown at all, and Hibernate even tells me it has updated the DB schema (which it has not, since no tables have been created.).

I have checked that the getAllArticles() method gets called during runtime using a debugger.

I really don't know what to check now, if someone has any idea I'll be grateful forever.

My servlet config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.last" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2/lastDB" />
        <property name="username" value="dbuser" />
        <property name="password" value="dbpass" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The entity:

```
package com.last.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class Article {


    private int id;
    private String content;
    private User author;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "CONTENT", length=10000)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name="AUTHOR")
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_USER_ID")
    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(User user) {
        this.author = user;
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
package com.last.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.last.entities.Article;
import com.last.entities.User;
import com.last.exceptions.DAOException;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(User.class).list();
    }


    @Override
    public User getUserByID(int id) {
        User result = (User) currentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();

        if (result == null) {
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.NO_RESULT);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {     
        return currentSession().createCriteria(Article.class).list();
    }
}
```

Tomcat's Log:

```
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Programmes\LaTeX\MikTeX\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;D:\Programming Stuff\Haskell\2010.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;D:\Programming Stuff\Haskell\2010.2.0.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\Programmes\PostgreSQL\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;F:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;F:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin;D:\Programming Stuff\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;D:\Programming Stuff\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin;F:\Web Server\wamp\ruby\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;D:\Programmes\NetBeans\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;.
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1055 ms
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [128] milliseconds.
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration D:\Programming Stuff\Projects\FinalTest\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\Last.xml
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Last' did not find a matching property.
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:15 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:15 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 22 16:39:15 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:15 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/last-servlet.xml]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:16 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:16 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1312f348: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,mainController,DAOImpl,serviceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.last.controllers.MainController.showHomePage(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@6192fb7a] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3389 ms
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'last'
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'last': initialization started
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'last-servlet': startup date [Mon Apr 22 16:39:18 CEST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/last-servlet.xml]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b2cc445: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,mainController,DAOImpl,serviceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1312f348
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.last.controllers.MainController.showHomePage(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:18 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1583f012] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'last': initialization completed in 503 ms
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
avr. 22, 2013 4:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7587 ms
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be copy-paste, but your hibernate session factory bean is scanning `com.test` for hibernate entities instead of `com.last`.

Comment: I think I love you. I refactored some stuff, but eclipse did not rename this part. Thank you !